# How to change datetime format with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, formatting

After importing data from an Excel file I get the Following output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


#On récupère le fichier Excel
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\YannickLECROART\\Desktop\\comedie.xlsx", skiprows=1)

series_comm = df.iloc[:, 1:3]
```

[image]

But what I would like to do now is to change the datetime format to get the Following result in my date colum:

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

instead of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.0000000 from the originated file

The purpose is Simply to get rid of all those zeros as you can see.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: Maybe need `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

Comment: This is what I get when I print df.dtypes: COME                           object
238                             int64
2017-01-01 00:00:00.0000000    object
dtype: object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` function:

```
In [1028]: df['date'] = df['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Comment: I get an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\YannickLECROART\Miniconda3\envs\machinelearning\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)

KeyError: 'date'

Comment: Please use the correct column name for the date column in your dataframe. I used  `date`, you should replace it with yours.

Comment: parking places_occupees date
COME 238 2017-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
COME 238 2017-01-01 00:01:00.0000000  I renammed the column but still an error message what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `df.columns`?

Comment: Thank you Mayank et Jezrael the function pd.to_datetime works lfine. You made me realize that I made a mistake when reading the file as I used the parameter skiprows=1 so there was no way it could find the date column… Take care guys